# How can a MATLAB program test whether MATLAB can render a particular font?

Tags: matlab, fonts, matlab-figure

I would like to use some special characters in a MATLAB figure.  How can my program ensure the fonts are available before using them?

listfonts() is not reliable.  It claims "Zapf Dingbats" is available on my machine, but it is not (and text() renders using a default font instead).  listfonts() always includes the standard PostScript fonts.  I suppose that's because they are always available for PostScript output, but I'm interested in displayed figures.  Likewise uisetfont() and MATLAB -> Preferences -> Fonts -> Custom list "Zapf Dingbats", but render the sample using a default font.

Just looking for the font file doesn't work, either.  For example, "Webdings" works fine on my main machine.  However, on a second machine, "Webdings" is installed (there's a file /Library/Fonts/Webdings.ttf, and Word can use it), but MATLAB substitutes a default font.

I thought of one test: Create a small figure with one marker symbol, use print() to write it to a .png file, read in the file as data, compute a hash, and compare that hash with a stored value.  Is there a less clumsy method?

I found Unicode equivalents for most of the symbols I need, that work for both of my test machines.  However, they too apparently depend on my having the right fonts installed.  For example, there are many Unicode versions of a square.  Hex codes 2588, 25a0, and 25fc work here, but 25fe, 2b1b, and 2bc0 are rendered as blank.  Is there a way to tell whether these characters are available?

I'm running R2017b under macOS version 10.13.5, and "set | grep LANG" displays "LANG=en_US.UTF-8".

Comment: as far as I can remember, matlab doesn't offer any way to "pick a font from your list of installed fonts" it lets you only use baked-in fonts, or you have to do explicit from-file loading. Did that change?

Comment: You can specify the desired font when you use text().  For example "text(.5,.5,'\fontname{wingdings 3}!')", or "text(.5,.5,'!','FontName','Wingdings 3')".